# Does the ISO 639 standard define mappings between ISO 639-5 language families and ISO 639-3 language?

Tags: standards

Does the ISO 639 standard define mappings between ISO 639-5 language families and ISO 639-3 language?

I’d like to know which ISO 639-5 language family an ISO 639-3 language belongs to. I don’t find any mappings between the two. Does the ISO standard define this? Or must I use third-party sources to find which family a language belongs to?

Answer (score 2):

ISO themselves do not define such a mapping, but there is now a mapping list by Jörg Tiedemann available that defines mapping between ISO 639-5 and  ISO 639-3 and it also includes Glottolog codes.

The list is available here

https://github.com/Helsinki-NLP/LanguageCodes/blob/master/data/iso639-5_to_iso639-3.tsv